# How to make the output of a script parsable

Tags: python, bash, parsing, formatting, solarwinds-orion

I have the following script https://github.com/peterpakos/checkipaconsistency

The script runs perfectly but none of the outputs are parsable by our monitoring tools (solarwinds), even using the Nagios plugin switch.

I am fairly new to this and I'm just after a way to edit the output of the script (preferably using bash) to make it parsable (1, 2, 3 for OK, WARNING and CRITICAL(which ironically are the output codes for Nagios that don't seem to be working)) - Solarwinds only parses numbers it seems or at least I can't get it to parse much else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the current output, and what output do you want instead?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to parse the table that appears under 'Example' in the page you linked? Assuming you could parse that, what kind of output would you need to get from the parser?

Comment: Check out the example perl scripts, on your Orion server, in \Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Orion\APM\SampleScriptMonitors\LinuxScripts. Especially the "Multi Value - Script Example (Top 10 Proccesses And Its CPU Usage).pl" script, as it shows how SolarWinds is expecting the scripts data to be returned.

Comment: A good Thwack post on SAM monitors, as well: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/docs/DOC-188909